# Where is the updated SVNKit 1.8.x javadoc?

Tags: javadoc, svnkit

I'm having trouble finding the javadoc for SVNKit 1.8.x. The javadoc that keeps seeming to pop up in my Google search is 1.7.x. While developing with 1.8.x, it appears that a lot of methods outlined in the javadoc have been deprecated. Is there a place with an updated javadoc for SVNKit 1.8?